# Display group of images from gallery

Tags: php, wordpress

My problem is two-part..

First, I want to grab images from the WP gallery and display in an unordered list. It is a row of company logos, all evenly sized and spaced, so an unordered list seems the best way to display.

Secondly, this should remain incredibly easy to edit by the site admin (no uploading and hovering over things to get ID's and definitely no code manipulation when images change over time).

So how can I grab a set of logos, where there may be 4-7 depending on how many the site admin wants to add, and place them in an unordered list?

If possible, I would like to lock in text for the first and last li with text.

I've searched images and categories, but unless I'm missing something, images to not have category attributes OOB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use visual composer or wp bakery page builder. You can set group image gallery and also single image. you can build your customize page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I'm hoping for some PHP help to get there.  This is just one small element on a custom template I've built, so I'm trying not to go with a plugin that may create unnecessary bloat for a tiny portion of the page.